# How to get the name and status of all steps in a spring batch job?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there any way to get the name and status of all steps in a [Job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/Job.html) from a [JobExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html) instance? Something similar to [JobExecution#getStepExecutions()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html#getStepExecutions--), but that method only returns the completed steps when I call it.

I need to know if a certain step is going to be part of a job or not and if it has completed. I need to know this in for example [JobExecutionListener#beforeJob](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html#beforeJob-org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution-).

Comment: I'm guessing that the dynamic nature of the model don't allow this even in cases where it's clear which steps will execute as part of a job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps aren't registered until you are actually about start them. Otherwise flow control (e.g. going to Step B vs C based on the exit code of Step A) wouldn't work.

So yes, you can get all steps that have been registered, but they won't all be registered at job startup.